# html 5 video not pausing on android device using pause() method

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, video

I'm having a problem, i'm trying to pause a video when pressing the android native back button, but it doesn't seem to work.

i have this code and it works fine whenever i press a jquery button (including `data-rel=back`)

but when i press the native back button, the page goes back successfully but the video keeps playing in the background.

here's my code which works with jquery buttons:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforehide", function () {
    $("video").each(function(){
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    }); 
});
```

This code above works and pauses videos whenever i change a page, so long as i'm pressing a jquery button.

I've even tried this, but it doesn't work for some reason?

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", goback , false);

function goback() {
    $("video").each(function(){
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    });
navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

In theory, i shouldn't need to place this code in the `goback()` function because it should be triggered on `pagebeforehide`, i can't understand why it's not doing this? Any reasons why?

Comment: Please note: the .play() or .pause() is not triggered whenever i press a native android button (such as the back button). It only triggers when i press a page changing button in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by myself, I used this simple code to fix it:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforehide", function () {
    $("video").each(function(){
    this.load();
    });
});
```

So before the page hides, it looks for each  tag in that page forcing it to stop playing and then reloads back to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
function playVid() { myVideo.play(); } 
function pauseVid() { myVideo.pause(); }
```

Comment: This doesn't work when i press the native back button. For some reason it doesn't trigger the .pause() event

Comment: user3594871: Hey, did you get this problem resolved?? I am also facing same problem. Please reply

Comment: @Rupesh Yep i did, please take a look at the answer below and hope this works for you too.